# Checking equality of objects following different attrbutes

Tags: python, oop

I have two lists of objects and I need to find matching objects according to two different sets of attributes. Let's say, I have Vehicle() objects and I need to first match all vehicles of the first list that are eqal to vehicles in the second, first looking on matching colors then looking on matching brands.
I have two solutions, but I am not sure if this is the best I can do. (I really need to optimise this performance wise)

So let's say I have:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, color, brand):
        self._color = color
        self._brand = brand
```

and lists of objects as such :

```
vehicles1= [Vehicle('blue','fiat'), Vehicle('red','volvo'), Vehicle('red','fiat')]

vehicles2 = [Vehicle('blue', 'volvo'), Vehicle('red', 'BMW')]
```

The first solution, which seems rediculously slow, is to work only by list inclusions :

```
inersect_brand_wise = [x for x in vehicles1 for y in vehicles2 if x._brand == y._brand]
```

then

```
 intersect_color_wise = [x for x in vehicles1 for y in vehicles2 if x._color == y._color]
```

The second solution I foud is to elaborate equality:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, color, brand):
        self._color = color
        self._brand = brand

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vehicle):
            return self._brand == other._brand
        return False
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self._color, self._brand))
```

Now getting the intersection brand-wise is trivial :

```
inersect_brand_wise = [x for x in vehicles1 if x in vehicles2]
```

in order to get intersection color-wise, I did the following :

```
class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, color, brand):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,color, brand)


def __hash__(self):
    return Vehicle.__hash__

def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Car):
        return other._color == self._color
    return False


def change_to_car(obj):
    obj.__class__ = Car
    return obj


cars1 = map(change_to_car, vehicles1)
cars2  = map(change_to_car, vehicles2)
```

And thus,

```
intersect_color_wise = [x for x in cars1 if x in cars2]
```

gives the second intersection.

However, this appears to me as a very clumsy way to do things, and I actually need good performance on this one.

Any suggestions on how to do better than all that?

Thanks in advance, 
M

Comment: What if you get the `set` of `brands` and `colors` in the compared against list first? i.e. `brands = {v._brand for v in vehicles2}; matches = [v for v in vehicles1 if v._brand in brands]`? It eliminates your complexity of iterating over `vehicles2` for each `vehicles1` iteration.

Comment: Is the explicit requirement getting two separate intersections?

Comment: `obj.__class__ = Car` – *woahhh, bad idea.*

Comment: @meowgoesthedog can you explain that?

Comment: @kebanus Yes, I need two separate intersections

Comment: Attributes such `__class__` are reserved and should not be written to; you should construct a new instance of `Car` instead. (Although for this example it's fine)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog that is what I wanted in the first place but something like Car(myvehicle) throws a TypeError. Do you by any chance have a suggestion?

Comment: Could you add some sample expectations?  I think I understand your requirement, but...  What I would do:  build 2 dicts keyed on (color, brand).  Then build 2 sets from their keys.  Find set intersection, which gives common keys.

Answer (score 0):

How is the performance in this case? Don't have a full set of data to emulate the performance for proper testing...:

```
def get_intersections(list1, list2):
    brands, colors = map(set, zip(*[(v._brand, v._color) for v in list2]))
    inter_brands = [v for v in list1 if v._brand in brands]
    inter_colors = [v for v in list1 if v._colors in colors]
    return inter_brands, inter_colors
```

You can also write individual intersections if you want:

```
from operator import attrgetter

def get_intersection(list1, list2, attr:str):
    getter = attrgetter(attr)
    t_set = {getter(v) for v in list2}
    results = [v for v in list1 if getter(v) in t_set]
    return results

# use it like this:
get_intersection(vehicles1, vehicles2, "_brand")
```

You can also scale the first function with `attrgetter` to get an arbitrary number of attributes:

```
def get_intersections(list1, list2, *attrs:str):
    getter = attrgetter(*attrs)
    if len(attrs) > 1:
        sets = list(map(set, zip(*[getter(v) for v in list2])))
    else:
        sets = [{getter(v) for v in list2}]
    results = {attr: [v for v in vehicles1 if getattr(v, attr) in sets[s]] for s, attr in enumerate(attrs)}
    return results
```

Test:

```
>>> get_intersections(vehicles1, vehicles2, "_brand", "_color")

{'_brand': [<__main__.Vehicle object at 0x03588910>], '_color': [<__main__.Vehicle object at 0x035889D0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x03588910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x035889F0>]}

>>> get_intersections(vehicles1, vehicles2, "_brand")

{'_brand': [<__main__.Vehicle object at 0x03588910>]}
```

Comment: Thaks for your suggestion. My data is quite big actually, so I don't know if duplicating things like that... And on my actual problem, I need to check on a list of attributes...

Comment: See my update, you can run it on individual attributes with `attrgetter`.  As far as I can see the problem with your original implementation is the complexity of `for x in v1... for y in v2`.  but you really don't need to check against `v2` more than once.

Comment: Ok this seems better, I will check that and come back to you. However, the problem is still that your t_set is essentially duplicating my data (because, aclually, colors and brands are never the same in each list - I should have presented an exemple with UserIds etc to be more clear)

Answer (score 0):

In fact Python is a dynamic language. That means that you can monkey patch the `Vehicle` class at will to make it suit your needs. You prepare 2 other classes (I made them subclasses of Vehicle so that autocompletion works in IDE) with respectively brand equality and color equality, and just assign their members to the Vehicle class:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, color, brand):
        self._color = color
        self._brand = brand

class Vehicle_brand(Vehicle):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._brand == other._brand
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._brand)


class Vehicle_color(Vehicle):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._color == other._color
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._color)
```

To obtain brand intersection:

```
Vehicle.__eq__ = Vehicle_brand.__eq__
Vehicle.__hash__ = Vehicle_brand.__hash__
intersect_brand_wise = [x for x in vehicles1 if x in vehicles2]
```

Then to obtain color intersection:

```
Vehicle.__eq__ = Vehicle_color.__eq__
Vehicle.__hash__ = Vehicle_color.__hash__
intersect_color_wise = [x for x in vehicles1 if x in vehicles2]
```

The good news here, is that if your `Vehicle` class has other members, they are left untouched when you change the equality part, and you never copy or duplicate any objects: only 2 methods in the class objects.

It may not be very OO pure, but it should work...

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Checking equality of objects following different attrbutes

Instead to find *equal* objects afterwards, doing `loop in loop`, check for *equality* at instantiation.
**To save `memory`**, save only the *equal* hashes of objects.

- Use `class attributs` to hold a `dict` of the `objects` from `set 1`
  and a `list` to hold the `_hash` of *equal* `objects`.

  ```
  class VehicleDiff:
      ref1 = {}
      _intersection = []

      def __init__(self, set, color, brand):
          self.color = color
          self.brand = brand
  ```
- Save a reference of `set 1` objects in the `dict ref1`.
  Check **only** objects from `set 2` against the `dict ref1` and **save only if equal**.

  ```
          _hash = hash((color, brand))
          if set == 1:
              VehicleDiff.ref1[_hash] = self

          elif _hash in VehicleDiff.ref1:
              VehicleDiff._intersection.append(_hash)
  ```
- Helper `methode intersection` to get a `VehicleDiff` object from `_hash`.

  ```
      @staticmethod
      def intersection():
          print('intersection:{}'.format(VehicleDiff._intersection))
          for _hash in VehicleDiff._intersection:
              yield VehicleDiff.ref1[_hash]
  ```
- String representation of a `VehicleDiff` object.

  ```
      def __str__(self):
          return 'color:{}, brand:{}'.format(self.color, self.brand)
  ```
- There is **no need** to hold the objects in a `list`.

  > **Note**: As the given example data have no intersection, I added `('red', 'fiat')` to `set 2`

  ```
  for p in [('blue', 'fiat'), ('red', 'volvo'), ('red', 'fiat')]:
      VehicleDiff(1, *p)

  for p in [('blue', 'volvo'), ('red', 'BMW'), ('red', 'fiat')]:
      VehicleDiff(2, *p)
  ```
- Print the result, **if any**.

  ```
  for vehicle in VehicleDiff.intersection():
      print('vehicle:{}'.format(vehicle))
  ```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> intersection:[2125945310]
> vehicle:color:red, brand:fiat
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***